# how do i divide JPanel in 70% 30%

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, japplet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Swing: How do I set a component height to the container's height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686882/swing-how-do-i-set-a-component-height-to-the-containers-height)

how do i divide JPanel like the picture shown below there are 2 panels panel1 and panel2
panel1 should take 70% and panel2 30% or panel1 should be bigger than panel2...
I have tried Gridlayout, Border Layout but its not working.any help would be appreciated.

```
public class TestApplication extends JApplet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel p1,p2;

    public void init(){         
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        p1=new JPanel();
        p2=new JPanel();

        p1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        p2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        add(p1);
        add(p2);
    }   
}
```

[image]

Comment: image uploaded was created in paint :)

Comment: Use GridBagLayout and use weighty=0.7 and 0.3 respectively

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you considered using a [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) ([How to Use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html))?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class TestApplication extends JApplet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel p1,p2;

    @Override
    public void init(){         
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        p1=new JPanel();
        p2=new JPanel();

        p1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        p2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        sp.setResizeWeight(0.7);
        sp.setEnabled(false);
        sp.setDividerSize(0);

        sp.add(p1);
        sp.add(p2);
        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }   
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have an external JFrame (or another JPanel) f, you can apply a BorderLayout and put p1 in NORTH and p2 in SOUTH. Then, using

```
Dimension df = f.getSize();
```

You will get the Dimension of the external Container (f).
Next, call to:

```
void setSize(Dimension d)
```

this way:

```
p1.setSize(new Dimension(df.getWidth(), df.getHeight()*0.7));
p2.setSize(new Dimension(df.getWidth(), df.getHeight()*0.3));
```

Finally, add these JPanels to its container.

Comment: If you use a LayoutManager, you should never call setSize. Either use LayoutManager's, constraints and as a last resort you can force pref/min/max size, or use absolute layout (`null`-layout) and you invoke setBounds/setLocation/setSize yourself. Mixing both in the same container is only looking for troubles.